# EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder & org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

**Spring Boot 1.1.5.RELEASE**

```
public class DataAccessTests
{
    private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        db = builder.setType(H2).addDefaultScripts().build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDataAccess() {
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(db);
        int r = template.queryForObject("select 1", Integer.class);
        assertEquals(r, 1);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        db.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-181]
```

Where I make a mistake?

Comment: Please say at what line the error occurs, or show stacktrace.

Comment: @Barlog what is the username/pasword you are setting, or show us the code where you are actually configuring it

Comment: It was assumed that this class is the entire application with config (the default settings from Spring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for my mistake. When I wrote a demo application for this error I found a solution.
The problem was that the settings were taken from my application rather than the default.
After I commented out`@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = App.class)` everything works fine.